# Using Asserts from Spring for validate user inputs in WebLogic 12C production Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm deploying a spring application on a weblogic server and I'm using Asserts, from the `org.springframework.util.Assert` package to validate the entries in my Rest service.

On my local host the Assert methods for validation work smoothly, returning errors for each user input. but in the production environment they do not work and only return Bad Request.

Has anyone gone through this before, or do you know how to solve it?

Comment: may be your Rest Controller expects some required parameter/headers , which you dont send in your request and thus  you get a Bad Request error, It has nothing to do with Assert. Its like a util class .

Comment: I found the problem. Is a server redirect.